# Is there a canonical way for determining if an HTTP response is in the 200 series in Java?

Tags: java, android, http, httpclient, http-status-codes

I currently have code that checks to see if an HTTP response has a 'success' status code.

```
// Accept any 200 series status code (200, 201, 202, 203, ...) 
// as being 'successful'.
if (response.status / 100 == 2) {
    // process response
} else {
    throw new Exception("Something went wrong...");
}
```

Is this the canonical way to do this? Or is there some other less ugly way to do this that I don't know of?

Comment: Honestly that code is not very descriptive right away. I would use `>= 200 && < 209` or whatever the limit is.

Comment: if status >= 200 and status < 300? Or am I misunderstanding the question (very likely)

Comment: Hey Matthew what is the Type of the resonse object?

Comment: I think it is cool. Use modulo too rarely :P .. if you want it to be descriptive, why dont you just put the statusCheck in a seperate method. isStatusOK(status) or something ?

Comment: @Peshal The response object doesn't really matter, let's just assume it exposes a field that contains an HTTP status integer such as 200.

Comment: @Kon Yeah that could work, I was kinda hoping there'd be some utility method that I didn't know about that handled this.

Comment: Using the modulo operator won't work: 200 % 100 = 0, 201 % 100 = 1, etc. What you want is `response.status / 100 == 2`.

Comment: @AdamS oh duh yeah you're right, thanks. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there is a canonical better way. If you have Jersey included you can write

```
Response.Status.Family.SUCCESSFUL == Response.Status.fromStatusCode(response.status).getFamily()
```

with the drayback that not all possible status codes are included in the `Status` enum. But even Jersey uses internally exact the algorithm posted by Adam to determine the `Family`.